# Do I need this whole class to find out if the fraction is reduced or not?

Tags: java, reduce

What I have to do is take 2 random variables for a fraction, 1 to 1000, and check to see if they are in reduced terms already or not. I do this 1,000 times and keep track of whether it was or wasn't in reduced terms.

Here is the main class

```
import java.util.*;

public class ratio1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int nonReducedCount = 0; //counts how many non reduced ratios there are
        for(int i =1; i<=1000; i++){

            Random rand = new Random();
            int n = rand.nextInt(1000)+1;  //random int creation
            int m = rand.nextInt(1000)+1;
            Ratio ratio = new Ratio(n,m);
            if (ratio.getReduceCount() != 0 ){ // if the ratio was not already fully reduced
                nonReducedCount++; // increase the count of non reduced ratios
            }   
        }

        int reducedCount = 1000 - nonReducedCount; //number of times the ratio was reduced already
        double reducedRatio = reducedCount / nonReducedCount; //the ratio for reduced and not reduced
        reducedRatio *= 6;
        reducedRatio = Math.sqrt(reducedRatio);
        System.out.println("pi is " + reducedRatio);
    }
}
```

And here is the class I am not sure about. All I want from it is to determine whether or not the fraction is already in simplest form. When I currently try to run it, it is giving me an error; "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Ratio.gcd (Ratio.java:67)
    at Ratio.gcd (Ratio.java:66)"

```
public class Ratio{
    protected int numerator; // numerator of ratio
    protected int denominator; //denominator of ratio
    public int reduceCount = 0; //counts how many times the reducer goes

    public Ratio(int top, int bottom)
    //pre: bottom !=0
    //post: constructs a ratio equivalent to top::bottom
    {
        numerator = top;
        denominator = bottom;
        reduce();
    }

    public int getNumerator()
    //post: return the numerator of the fraction
    {
        return numerator;
    }

    public int getDenominator()
    //post: return the denominator of the fraction
    {
        return denominator;
    }

    public double getValue()
    //post: return the double equivalent of the ratio 
    {
        return (double)numerator/(double)denominator;

    }
    public int getReduceCount()
    //post: returns the reduceCount
    {
        return reduceCount;
    }

    public Ratio add(Ratio other)
    //pre: other is nonnull
    //post: return new fraction--the sum of this and other
    {
        return new Ratio(this.numerator*other.denominator+this.denominator*other.numerator,this.denominator*other.denominator);

    }

    protected void reduce()
    //post: numerator and denominator are set so that the greatest common divisor of the numerator and demoninator is 1
    {
        int divisor = gcd(numerator, denominator);
        if(denominator < 0) divisor = -divisor;
        numerator /= divisor;
        denominator /= divisor;
        reduceCount++;
    }

    protected static int gcd(int a, int b)
    //post: computes the greatest integer value that divides a and b
    {
        if (a<0) return gcd(-a,b);
        if (a==0){
            if(b==0) return 1;
            else return b;

        }
        if (b>a) return gcd(b,a);
        return gcd(b%a,a);
    }
    public String toString()
    //post:returns a string that represents this fraction.
    {
        return getNumerator()+"/"+getDenominator();

    }   
}
```

Here are the lines of the error in the Ratio class;

```
if (b>a) return gcd(b,a);
        return gcd(b%a,a);
```

Answer (score 1):

A fraction is reducible if its GCD is greater than 1. You can compute the GCD with the static method given in Ratio, so you could instead use:

```
...
int n = rand.nextInt(1000)+1;
int m = rand.nextInt(1000)+1;
if(Ratio.gcd(n,m) == 1) {
    nonReducedCount++;
}
```

This saves you from instantiating a new Ratio instance.

If that method doesn't work for you, you can always use your own GCD calculator. This one is recursive too and similar to the one in Ratio:

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) { return b==0 ? a : gcd(b,a%b); }
```

You could Google it for non-recursive methods if the StackOverflowError is still a problem.

Comment: Wait nevermind I tried your second one and it works, but it is giving me the exact same value output every time I run it

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. You're not creating that `Random` instance with a seed, are you? Did you try printing some of the numbers?